# Узнаем ширину панели с кнопками на сенсорном экране

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, monogame

Хотел узнать как в `Android API` можно узнать ширину панели с кнопками (назад, домой, окна).

Comment: посмотрите вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264268/how-do-i-get-the-height-and-width-of-the-android-navigation-bar-programmatically/29938139#29938139) или [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264268/how-do-i-get-the-height-and-width-of-the-android-navigation-bar-programmatically) для ,насколько я понял,не физических кнопок

Comment: @ОлегКотенко я попробовал второй вариант, но проблема в том, что он мне `Context.GetResources()` ругается на эту запись, можете подсказать, как для C# это исправить

Comment: ,вряд ли, я C# не знаю. Но странно, а что пишет?

Comment: @ОлегКотенко что нет такого метода, может надо что-то подключить

Comment: По идее класс контекста есть в jdk, как он интерпретируется для c# я не знаю, но у гугла есть что ответить на "[контекст только для с#](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11102/what-is-equivalent-to-getapplicationcontext-in-xamarin-android)"